# Scala's position variance

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I am reading Programming in Scala and I want to clear out some things regarding the rules that the compiler deduces whether a position is negative, neutral or positive and what exactly is defined as a position.

I know that this question has been asked a lot here but reading those answers confused me even more.

So taking the example from the book and changing it a bit so I can express easier my question.

```
abstract class Cat[-T, +U] {
    def meow[W](par1: T, par2: Cat[U,T], par3: Double): Cat[Cat[U, T], U]
}
```

So the questions are:

- The book initially specifies that a position is every spot inside the code that a type parameter may be used (i.e. everywhere T and U can be) and later specifies that all value parameters are positions, Does this mean that `par3` in my example is a position?
- `par1`'s `T` is a negative position because in the outer "scope" everything is positive and inside method value parameters the position's sign changes and takes the opposite value of the outer scope. With the same reasoning `par2`'s `Cat[U,T]` position as a whole is negative. Am I right on these?
- The `U` and `T` inside `par2` `Cat[U,T]` are positive and negative respectively. The reason that this happens is because of the rule that is being used in the previous bullet?
- In the book there is another rule that says position sign flipping happens also in the case:

  > inside type arguments of types such as the `Arg` in `C[Arg]`, when the corresponding type argument of `C` has the type parameter defined with contravariance

  That is as I understand refers to the case of `C` defined as below

  ```
  class C[-T]
  ```

  Well if this works as I understand shouldn't in the previous bullet's case this rule also apply and thus have `par2`'s `Cat[U,T]` have the `U`'s position flipped (again), because in `Cat` class definition the first type parameter is defined with contravariance?

Now onto the return type

- `Cat[Cat[U, T], U]` as a whole is positive because there is no rule or anything to say for it to change sign. Same logic to the rightmost U because Cat is covariant to the second type parameter.
- The inner `Cat[U, T]` has negative position because of the bullet 4. 
  Normally it would have + by inheriting the outer scope sign but a flip is happening because of bullet 4.
- What are the rules for the `U` and `T` inside the inner `Cat` in the return type to have + and - signs respectively? Does the "type nesting" have any role on the signs?

Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All you questions in form "Am I right?" could be answered as "Yes you right".
Last question about type nesting could be answered as

> **type nesting plays key role in variance calculation**

We could minimize rules simply replacing every method type with corresponding function type, so your type could be represented as

```
abstract class Cat[-T, +U] {
    type Meow[W] = (T, Cat[U,T], Double) => Cat[Cat[U, T], U]
    def meow[W]: Meow[W]
}
```

next, understanding that every `FunctionN` has N+1 type arguments, first N of which as contravariant and last one is covariant and `Meow` is application of `Function3` we can draw some type tree

[image: type tree]

Root of the tree is newly defining type, `class Cat` in your case. It could be understood as product of all of its members, so if more `def`\ `val`\ `var`\ `type` members were presented, more nodes under `Cat[-U, +T]` should be drawn along with the `Meow` type

Here we must ensure that every occurrence of covariant parameter should have a "positive" path, i.e. even count of red/negative/covariant edges from the root, and every occurrence of contravariant should have "negative" path with odd count of red edges.

Note also, that there could be a neutral path - a path, where at least one invariant type parameter edge occurs. That path **must** end with invariant type parameter or some irrelevant type

Comment: The root in the tree shouldn't be Cat[-T,+U] ? Also you mean even instead of event right?

Comment: @user183833 yes, thank you. See paragraph right after the image